# Broken pytorch installation

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I was trying to install pytorch, I went to the official website and copied the command for windows 10, pip, cuda 11.8, so it should be correct. My first installation failed because I had too little space (I am mentioning this because it MIGHT be important in future issues?). I cleared plenty of space to make sure it's enough, and tried installing again: it got to "2.7/2.7", and hang around there for a while, I then did something that I really shouldn't have, which is close the command prompt. After launching the download again, my pc froze and I had to force shut down it. Looking at my free space I could see the 2.7 gigs are there, but each time I tried installing again it would freeze my pc and I had to force shut down again.

I went to my python folder but couldn't find the folder with the libraries pip installed (I remember them being in scripts, but I guess I was wrong). Checking pip list "pytorch" nor "torch" is there, and doing pip uninstall "torch" or "pytorch" it says there's no such library.

So basically, I can't finish the installation, I can't delete it either, and I just don't know what to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pytorch and required packages may ask for more than 2.7 gigabytes in total. You'd need to keep in memory the downloaded package *and* the installed packages, which may easily overflow 4 gigabytes. Try again by freeing up to 10 gigabytes at least

Comment: At the time I had over 10 gigabytes cleaned up. I now decided to try installing cuda so it ate up all of the space (and still failed in the end for no reason, which is another thing I'll have to deal with now). But at least I know where cuda is installed, and I can delete it, I can't find pytorch to delete the failed installation and try again, and it was also freezing my pc even when there was plenty of space.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up more space again (over 10gb as @Domenico suggested) and installed the cuda 12.1 version of pytorch, it got to the end, froze again, but after some time it unfroze, though was still stuck. A random reddit comment from a year ago said to tab in and press enter a bunch, I did that and it worked. It also got stuck on installing, but the same method worked again, and my pytorch installation works correctly.

Apparently pressing tab and enter can sometimes help with various cmd processes getting stuck.